# Cannot make button non-interactable through seperate script

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, static

I'm trying to make a button interactable after a certain scene (playing level) has been loaded. It's a button in a menu scene that represent the loaded scene itself (level selectable after playing it).

The problem is this: If the users passes a certain level, say level 1, level 2 gets loaded, and a static method gets called:

```
public static void AllowTut2()
{
    Tut2Allowed = true; //public static bool initialised in this script
    tutorial2.interactable = true; //tutorial2 is a button in the "menu scene"
}
```

To make it clear where the variables come from, this is part of the same script:

```
public class LevelSelectScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Button tutorial2;
public static bool Tut2Allowed = false; 
//...some other variables

  void Start () 
  {
  tutorial2 = tutorial2.GetComponent<Button>();
  tutorial2.enabled = false;    //more later on
  ///... some other code
  }
}
```

Now the problem is this error: An object reference is required to access non-static member `LevelSelectScript.tutorial2' (refers to method AllowTut2).

It seems that I cannot change tutorial2.interactable trough the given static method (called in another script).

It basically says the button tutorial2 is non-static, therefore cannot use this in a static method.

Now if I make the button static, i.e. change

```
public Button tutorial2;
```

to

```
public static Button tutorial2;
```

then I have no way to assign the button object in the scene to this variable in the attached script.

Does someone perhaps know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the unity3d tag instead of the unity tag

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use static varaibles and also use inspector for assigning you can use singleton  , [here](http://rusticode.com/2014/01/21/creating-game-manager-using-singleton-pattern-and-monobehaviour-in-unity3d/) is where you can learn it

Comment: But the name "tutorial2" is already the instance of an Object (Button) declared as shown in the code.

Comment: use singleton instead